# SSIS And Parallel Inserts

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016 they introduced parallel inserts into existing tables. By not having certain features on the target table SQL Server can insert the data in parallel streams.

Using the syntax of 
    INSERT [tableName] WITH (TABLOCK)
    SELECT .....

The data will be inserted in parallel. I have seen great improvements using this. What normally would take about 10 minutes to insert 120 million, using this new feature takes only about 30 seconds.

How can I use this new setting in SSIS? I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and SQL Server 2016. 
I know I can use a "Execute SQL Task" and put something like this in, but what I'm wondering is how to use this in the Data Flow? Is there a specific Connection Manager and setting in the Destination Adapter?

Comment: Refer this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522534.aspx

Comment: @KinchitDalwani I looked at that article. It was very informative about what the new upgrades are, but I didn't see anything about parallel inserts. Did I just miss it?

Comment: This might can answer your question: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

in sql server 2016, we need to provide two condition for using parallelism for our insert operations. The first one is compatibility level of database must be set at 130. So before you run your ssis package check your database compatibility level.

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases
```

the second condition is using TABLOCK hint. In SSIS Package you can choose TABLOCK hint with OLEDB Destination.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot utilize Parallel inserts in DTF.
According to [Microsoft description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/07/06/sqlsweet16-episode-3-parallel-insert-select/) of Parallel Inserts in SQL 2016, it can be used only if executing `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement with some limitations. Data Flow prepares data table in memory of SSIS Server, OLEDB or ODBC destination will try to load it with 'INSERT`or`INSERT BULK` statements, which are not subject to parallel operations.